# Node.js performance: small separate modules vs long script

Tags: node.js

I have a script that should analyze incoming data in many ways and then return response based on it. So in general the workflow looks like this:

```
/* step 1 */
var step1_var1, step1_var2, ...;
if (initial_data.val1 === '...') {
    step1_var1 = '...';
    ...
}

/* Step 2 */
var step2_var1, ...;
if (step1_var1 === '...' && initial_data.val2 === '...') {
    step2_var1 = ...;
}
else if (...) {
    db.find(...);
}

...
```

Each step in this flow may depend on the results of previous steps, however steps are each a separate piece of logic.
As the script is getting longer and more complex I want to isolate each step into a separate module.

The problem is that I need to store results of all computations and pass them to each module. I can do it sort of like this:

```
/* main.js */
var results = {};
var step1 = require('./step1');
var step2 = require('./step2');
...
step1(initial_data, results);
step2(initial_data, results);
...

/* step1.js */
module.exports = function (initial_data, results) {
    results.step1 = {};
    if (initial_data.val1 === '...') {
        results.step1.var1 = '...';
        ...
    }
}

/* step2.js */
module.exports = function (intial_data, results) {
    results.step2 = {};
    if (results.step1.var1 === '...' && initial_data.val2 === '...') {
        results.step2.var1 = ...;
    }
    else if (...) {
        db.find(...);
    }
}
```

I want to know if from the performance and memory usage point of view there is a problem of calling many such modules and passing `results` back and forth?